# How to carry out synchronous processes in TCL

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to carry out two process in parallel. Help me in writing a code in tcl which carries out two processes synchronously in TCL.

Comment: Your question is rather confusing to me at the moment. When you say “process”, what do you mean? Is this running Tcl code within the current interpreter, or running Tcl code in another interpreter, or running subprocesses? Also, “synchronously” means what precisely? Helping us understand what ***you*** mean by this will help us help you achieve your goal (or at least be able to tell you for that it is impossible, though I suspect that's not the case).

Comment: by "two process" i mean to say two different processes starting them at the same time within the current interpreter

Comment: Thanks; that was what I needed to figure out how to give you a reasonable answer.

Comment: I think you should replace the word "synchronous" with "simultaneous" since running the two processes one after another (not at the same time) is usually what "synchronous" means.

Answer (score 2):

In Tcl, there are two ways to run a pair of subprocesses “at the same time”.

### Simplest: *Without* control

If you just want to fire off two processes at once without keeping any control over them, put an ampersand (`&`) as the last argument to `exec`:

```
exec process1 "foo.txt" &
exec process2 "bar.txt" &
```

Note that, apart from the process ID (returned by `exec`) you've got no control over these subprocesses at all. Once you set them going, you'll essentially never hear from them again (using appropriate redirections to/from standard in/out may well be advisable!)

### More complex: *With* control

To keep control over a subprocess while running it in the background, make it run in a pipeline created with `open`. The syntax for doing so is rather odd; be sure to follow it *exactly* (except as noted below):

```
set pipelineChannel1 [open |[list process1 "foo.txt" ] "r"]
set pipelineChannel2 [open |[list process2 "bar.txt" ] "r"]
```

These are reader pipelines where you're consuming the output of the subprocesses; that's what the (optional) `r` means. To get a pipeline that you write to (i.e., that you provide input to) you use `w` instead, and if you want to *both* read and write, use `r+`. The pipelines are then just normal channels that you use with `puts`, `gets`, `read`, `fconfigure`, etc. Just `close` when you are done.

The `|` must come outside and immediately before the `[list …]`. This matters especially if the name of the command (possibly a full pathname) has any Tcl metacharacters in it, and is because the [specification of `open`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/open.htm#M21) says this:

> If the first character of *fileName* is “**|**” then the remaining characters of *fileName* are treated as a list of arguments that describe a command pipeline to invoke, in the same style as the arguments for **exec**.

The main things to beware of when working with a pipeline are that.

- The processing of the subprocesses really is asynchronous. You need to take care to avoid forcing too much output through at once, though turning on non-blocking IO with `fconfigure $channel -blocking 0` is usually enough there.
- The other processes can (and frequently do) buffer their output differently when outputting to a pipeline than when they're writing to a terminal. If this is a problem, you'll have to consider whether to use a package like Expect (which can also run multiple interactions at once, though that should be used much more sparingly as virtual terminals are a much more expensive and limited system resource than pipelines).

If you're doing truly complex asynchronous interactions with the subprocesses, consider using Tcl 8.6 where there are Tcllib packages built on top of the base coroutine feature that make keeping track of what's going on much easier.